# Can't get != to work on iterator variable

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

My problem lies within the comparison operator " if combination[0] != b ". I want the first digit of the "combination" variable to not be equal to the digits that are in the "badnumbers" list (so no combinations that start with 0,5 and 6), yet for some reason that code is ignored as shown when the program is run. However, if i change the comparison operator from != to == the program works just fine (as in only combinations that start with 0,5 and 6 are printed).

My code:

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
totalcombinations = []
for i in numbers:
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            for b in badnumbers:
                if combination[0] != b and combination not in totalcombinations:
                    totalcombinations.append(combination)
                    
for c in totalcombinations:
  print(c)
```

I tried using "if combination[0] != b " at first, then "if str(combination[0]) != b" and have used ChatGPT to get some answers yet nothing worked. I expected there to not be any combination starts with 0, 5 and 6 to be printed.

Comment: It would be much smarter to put `if i in badnumbers:` / `continue` as the first statement in your `for i` loop.  Also, you can make `totalcombinations` a `set` and avoid the "already included" test.

Comment: Also, `for n in range(1000):` / `if n < 100 or n in range(500,700):` / `continue` would do all of this in 1 loop instead of four.

Comment: leaving aside the inefficiencies, think about it, you are looping through `badnumbers`. Suppose `combinations` is `000`. On the first iteration of `badnumbers`, the `if` condition is false, and it doesn't do anything. On the next iteration, `b` is `'5'`, so it *will* get appended

Comment: Also take a look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  `totalcombinations = list(itertools.product('1234789',range(10),range(10)))` would give you the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `for b in badnumbers:` loop. What this loop is doing is, for example, for the combination 000:

1. It compares the first digit of 000, so 0 to the first item of the `badnumbers` list. The first number of this list is 0, so the combination won't be added to `totalcombinations`, just as you expect.
2. However, than it compares 0 to the second item of `badnumbers`, to the 5. 5 is not equal to 0 and this combination is not in `totalcombinations`, so it **will** be added to the list of `totalcombinations`.
3. The same is done in the last iteration, but the combination is already in the list of `totalcombinations`.

One of easiest solutions that does not require changing that much code would be

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
totalcombinations = []
for i in numbers:
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            if not (combination[0] in badnumbers) and combination not in totalcombinations:
                totalcombinations.append(combination)
                    
for c in totalcombinations:
  print(c)
```

The `for b in badnumbers` loop is removed, instead `if not (combination[0] in badnumbers)` is used to check if the first digit is present in the list of `badnumbers`, although it would be possible to rewrite the code with way less lines.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the good comments, the test of any concatenated string will pass the "!=" test of one of the bad number digits and subsequently append the string to the total combination list.

With that, you probably would just want to simplify the test condition to not include a concatenated string unless the first character/digit is not in the bad number list.  Following is a refactored version for your study.

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
totalcombinations = []
for i in numbers:
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            # Simplified test
            if combination[0] not in badnumbers and combination not in totalcombinations:
                totalcombinations.append(combination)

for c in totalcombinations:
    print(c)
```

Following is some of the sample output at the terminal denoting the skipping of strings starting with any of the bad number digits.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/BadNumbers$ python3 BadNumbers.py 
100
101
102
103

496
497
498
499
700
701
702
703
704
```

Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

We have a list numbers that contains all the digits from '0' to '9' and a badnumbers list that contains the digits '0', '5', and '6'. We start with an empty totalcombinations list to store valid combinations. We use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements in the `numbers` list. For each element `i`, which represents the first digit of the combination, we check if `i` is not in the badnumbers list using the `if i not in badnumbers` condition.

If `i is not in the badnumbers` list, we proceed to generate combinations. We use two nested for loops to generate all possible combinations for the second and third digits, w and l, respectively.

We create the combination by concatenating the three digits (i, w, and l) and add it to the totalcombinations list.

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
totalcombinations = []

for i in numbers:
    if i not in badnumbers:
        for w in numbers:
            for l in numbers:
                combination = i + w + l
                totalcombinations.append(combination)

for c in totalcombinations:
    print(c)
```

and one liner would be like:

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']

# Generate all combinations and filter out the bad ones
totalcombinations = [i + w + l for i in numbers for w in numbers for l in numbers if i not in badnumbers]

for c in totalcombinations:
    print(c)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes my bad, it should be solved now.

Comment: It should be now good with both versions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hope it is sufficient enough now!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid combinations starting with digits in badnumbers. you can using the `if i in badnumbers: continue` as the first statement in the loop.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
badnumbers = {"0", "5", "6"}  
totalcombinations = set()
for i in numbers:
    if i in badnumbers:
        continue
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            totalcombinations.add(combination)
for c in totalcombinations:
    print(c)
```

> My code generates three-digit combinations excluding those starting with 0, 5, or 6.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the problem is one of logic. The opposite of "`i == b` for any `b` in `badnumbers`" is not "`i != b` for any `b` in `badnumbers`" but "`i != b` for **all** `b` in `badnumbers`".

You can use `for`-`else` for this (`else` should really have been named something like `nobreak` to make it clear what it does).

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
totalcombinations = []
for i in numbers:
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            for b in badnumbers:
                if i != b and combination not in totalcombinations:
                    break
            else:
                totalcombinations.append(combination)
                    
for c in totalcombinations:
  print(c)
```

Now there's a major inefficiency here: you're checking a whole lot of things you don't need to.

For example, `i` only changes once every 100 inner loops, so you don't need to check this.

And `combination` is never going to be in `totalcombinations`, because every number is unique.

We also don't need to loop over `badnumbers` explicitly, we can use `in` here:

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
totalcombinations = []

for i in numbers:
    if i in badnumbers:
        continue # just go to the next i
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            totalcombinations.append(combination)
                    
for c in totalcombinations:
  print(c)
```

Now, you could also improve this even further because you know beforehand which numbers you don't want to start with: (especially useful if you want to run that loop multiple times.

```
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
startnumbers = [num in numbers if num not in badnumbers]
totalcombinations = []

for i in startnumbers:
    for w in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
            combination = i + w + l
            totalcombinations.append(combination)
                    
for c in totalcombinations:
  print(c)
```

And of course, `itertools` can help you out as well:

```
from itertools import product

numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
badnumbers = ['0', '5', '6']
startnumbers = [num in numbers if num not in badnumbers]
totalcombinations = list(f'{i}{w}{l}' for i, w, l in product(startnumbers, numbers, numbers))
```

Comment: The logic I mentioned in the first paragraph is an application of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which in Python can be expressed as `not (a or b) == not a and not b` and `not (a and b) == not a or not b`